# How can I debug my Rails application which encountered an internal server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.1 on Ubuntu.

My application is running just fine on the local development environment. When I moved everything to the production environment server, and tried the application URL, I got the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

The log file (production.log) has in it something about the migrations, but nothing else.

Where do I get started trying to figure out what this is about?

Comment: google on the exact error message?

Comment: Can you be more specific on this *something about the migrations*?

Comment: Stjin: I meant that the migrations completed properly, and this was reflected in the log file, but nothing after that

Comment: rene: google it? this is a standard 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24526719/4):

I followed the instructions and set up an environment variable for the secret_key. It turns out Rails 4.1 cannot read it and this seems to be a known issue. So, I had to put the key directly into secrets.yml and this solved the problem